# How do I load video from my MySQL DB into my website?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, video

I have uploaded a video into my MySQL DB and saved it under a BLOB column, now how do I load this data into my HTML / PHP webpage?

(I know saving video in a MySQL DB isn't recommended, but work with me on this. I'm doing this for learning purposes)

I've looked into doing this mostly with HTML, but I don't think inserting a directory through a PHP variable would work, as it's saved in my DB and not in a folder I can specify.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to grab it from db and save into a file on disk and then play it. (i did not test it myself, but it should work)
after saving it into the file redirect browser to another page like this (you can pass the movie location in address or session or other ways). my example pass in url:

try this:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/movie', $my_blob_movie);
header("Location: playmovie.php?location=/path/to/movie");
die();
```

and in playmovie.php get location as this:

```
$location = $_GET['location'];
```

and then play file....

Comment: I'm writing the code to try this out now, but if you could help me along my way, that'd be great. I'm splitting this into two pages; one where the video is loaded, and one where it is displayed. I want the first page to automatically forward the user to the next page when the 'download' is finished. Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify:

> I've looked into doing this mostly with HTML, but I don't think
>   inserting a directory through a PHP variable would work, as it's saved
>   in my DB and not in a folder I can specify.

If you've got php and can create new scripts and upload them by FTP or whatever, you should be able to modify your upload script to write to a file.

Anyways, if it is uploaded using a web from, the file is already on your server.

In any case, you could write a php script to read the data from the database, and echo it out, after setting the HTTP Content-Type header:

```
// connect to DB and query for data

header("Content-Type: video/quicktime"); // Specify the mime type fr the specific video format

// output the video now
echo $videoblobdata;
```

See the Internet video mime types on Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_video

Comment: Like I said, the video is uploaded to the MySQL Database. I'm avoiding using a Fileserver entirely.

Comment: It is an unusual situation, but I updated my answer to cover your situation anyway! Hope that helps.

Comment: @Makkebakke quick question.. Your comment on Mehdi's answer, suggests you're trying to save as a file now. Or do you mean you're trying the header content type code? Just curious, no worries.

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't know how to implement your suggestion. I'm trying Mehdi's suggestion first and if that doesn't work I'll get back to you. Even if I don't get to it, thank you very much.

Comment: @Makkebakke ok. If you succeed with writing to a file as Medhi describes, then that's the better solution anyway. Otherwise Id be glad to update my answer again with more detail, just ask if you decide.